# good practise to handle composer, shebang and self-compiled php-versions?

Tags: php, composer-php, shebang

I've started a new project in which I like to used the current version of PHP (5.5.12). I compiled this version myself because the version of my distro is 5.3.

I need propel ORM so I installed it via composer.

Now, the propel-script uses this shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

which of course calls the main PHP (5.3) and not my self-compiled one. Unfortunately propel needs PHP >= 5.4 and I cannot execute the script without errors.
So my quick-and-dirty solution is to replace the first line in the propel-script with:

```
#!/opt/php-5.5.12/bin/php
```

which works, but is not update-safe. At least I think this could be replaced by doing a composer-update.
I still need the 5.3-version for other projects, so using an alias is no solution for me.
It's maybe some petty problem, but is there a finer way to combine 3rd-party-libraries via composer with a self-compiled php executable?

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to use [`vagrant`](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and setup a virtual machine environment where php5.5 is installed. You could setup an [Ubuntu 14.04](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/) for example, it contains PHP version 5.5.

Developing on your physical machine is sooo yesterday! ;)